# Is there a way to import a blank text file to create a single record with zero for value?

Tags: ms-access, import

I'm importing two text files into two separate existing tables based on a user inputted shipment no. Sometimes one of the files has no data in it. I would like that file import to create a single record with 0 as the value. Only one column is being imported and it is an integer. I need the record created because I'm adding the shipment no to each record in the table after importing. This table represents a part type. I need to have at least one record for this part type as it will be used in an update query.

Honesty, I don't even know where to start to create a single record with value 0.

Comment: We need a bit more info. What programming language is this being written in? (I'm guessing VBA based on your username). What code do you have so far? If you're new to all of this SQL stuff, I'd suggest a SQL tutorial like: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Comment: I don't think import could do it but could just INSERT a record when the text file is empty.

Comment: You could use `FileLen` to get the file size. If the file size is greater than 0, import the file, otherwise you could use an `INSERT` statement as @June7 suggests or else import a pre-prepared file with 0 in. The latter option might be more flexible as you can change the value if needed outside of modifying code.

Comment: Sorry this is in an Access Database. I need the table to have at least one record so I can add the shipment number to that record. The value needs to be zero as I have a query that sums that column.